# Authorisation Key in Karate API

Tags: api, bdd, karate

Hi  I am new to karate framework and trying to create a basic scenarios.I am using swagger to automate scenarios and in swagger I need to enter Authorisation key before executing any scenarios. I have entered the Authorisation key, but I am getting 404 error.

Below is my feature file

```
Feature: Add a new student to the application
Background:
* url 'https://dev-api.com'
* header Authorization = '3456-9876-1234-8907' // swagger Authorisation key

Scenario: Create a new User
Given path '/swagger/ui/Member_Post'
And request 
"""
{
"FName": "Mark",  
"LName": "Smith",
"Initials": "M",
"Title": "Mr",
"Sex": "Male",
"DateOfBirth": "26-05-2021",     
"ID": "Student01",
"Status": "Active"
 }
 """ 
When method POST
Then status 201
```

Also in another scenario, I want to add address of student.How do I pass student ID in feature file. For example for student ID Student01, i want to add address,scored marks in exam

Comment: Isn't your spelling wrong for Authorisation instead of `Authorization`? also when you get issues like 404 status, it is for sure a mistake from your side and nothing to do with Karate DSL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I changed it to Authorization still getting the same error. Ya it has nothing to with Karate. I am new to karate and trying to understand why I am getting 404 .

Comment: Your API endpoint seems incorrect.

Comment: I directly copied from swagger url - 'https://dev-api.com/swagger/ui/Member_Post'. I hope we can use Swagger url in Karate